Example on deformation Theory
I am trying to follow Liu's Notes on deformation theory, as an support for Hartshorne's book on deformation theory.
But right in the beginning of the notes that I am not being able to prove. Given a small extension in the category of local Artinian algebras with residue field equals to $K$, $0 \to \ker \phi \to B \to^{\phi} A$, and a homomorphism from $f: R = K[[x_1,\cdots,x_d]] \to A$, we would like to understand how can we lift $f$ to $F: R  \to B$.
Liu's notes says that we always can lift such map in this situation because it is enough to lift the images of the $x_i's$. That is ok. Now, we have a short exact sequence:
$$0 \to Hom(R, \ker \phi) \to Hom(R,B) \to Hom(R,A) \to 0. $$
This is also ok, we just proved the last arrow is an epimorphism. He then claims that $Hom(R, \ker \phi) \simeq (M_{R}/M_{R}^2)^{\vee} \otimes \ker \phi$, but I was not able to prove that. Has anyone have a hint?
Thanks in advance

That's not what is claimed in the exercise. You're just supposed to find a surjective homomorphism $(\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2)^{\vee}\otimes\mathrm{ker}(\phi)\to \hom(R,\mathrm{ker}(\phi))$.
